# Android Multipoint Circular range bar control

Tags: android, user-interface, range, android-custom-view

Hi recently i am working on project where user required to provide more than one range into circular rangebar, tried many way to accomplish it but with no luck, so is there any one who accomplished such control or anyone who can guide me to develop one?[image]

Comment: hey i am trying to achieve the same have u done it?

Comment: Hi , you can use https://github.com/apptik/MultiSlider and extend it to show a circle instead of a line.

Comment: Please share what you've done so far, so others can help

Comment: Can you please describe your exact task?